# How is Logitech C510 HD Webcam

Tags: webcam

I am going to buy Logitech C510 HD webcam and I just checked on other questions here on AskUbuntu that it works out of the box with cheese. Jorge's response also confirm this and I feel confident buying it now.

My question is can it be limited in any functionality that I would like to do with it?
I would like it to be used with everything - Skype, Gtalk video chat, Facebook, Youtube etc. Also this may sound lame but I need to know whether I could record or do a video call in lesser resolution video (its a 720p one)?

Edit: Ported part of this question to another question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [comment](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9654221&postcount=3) on the forums confirms that the camera works when you're plug it in. The older C500 shows up as [supported in Linux](http://www.quickcamteam.net/devices) on the Logitech page, but unfortunately that page hasn't been updated for the C510.

However mrubli from Logitech [posts](http://forums.quickcamteam.net/showthread.php?tid=1273) on their forum:

> All these cameras are UVC compliant and work well on Linux.

So you should be good to go with support; as far as being able to encode with the GPU and all that you might want to split those off into seperate questions so we can get down to specifics.

I personally have had great success with Logitech webcams in Linux and I can do Cheese, Skype, and Google Talk, etc with an older Quickcam STX, if you end up with this webcam please leave a comment on how well it works!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jorge!
I did so. Another question is here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/30222/gpu-on-the-fly-encoding-of-video-through-logitech-hd-webcam-c510

Can you answer if it would be possible to record at lower resolutions? Most probably it would be, but I just wanted to confirm that else it won't be of much use to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've bought the Logitech C510 HD camera today. I can say that it's working very good in latest version of Mint 11, which is based on Ubuntu 11.04, so there should be no difference.
Here are a couple of advises. If you want to record your self use guvcview instead of chease software because in chease you can't get the full frame rate, at least I don't know how.

I have tested the camera on google video (for which you need to download their plugin, that should take a minute) and with skype, both work very good.
Hope this helps some one in the future.