# Is Logitech HD Webcam C615 supported?

Tags: drivers, webcam

Is Logitech HD Webcam C615 supported under Ubuntu? 
The list of drivers can be found here: 
http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/ 
But Logitech HD C510 is not on that list and I have that camera and it works great, is it so with HD C615?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I bought the cammera.
Let me give you an update. Everyone of thinking of buying this camera on Linux should do so. This is the best thing I've ever seen, full HD 1920x1080 works perfectly 30fps with guvcview. Picture quality is amazing, all working out of the box, just plug and play.

UPDATE:
Camera works fine on LTS 12.04.

UPDATE2:
Camera works fine on 12.10.

Comment: I bought this device based on this review and can also confirm the thing just works.  Walked up to my running Ubuntu 12.04 box, plugged it in and sound and video just worked instantly.  Just amazing...threw the stupid windows driver disk away 10 minutes later.

Comment: Did the microphone work fine as well?

Comment: @Hugo yes microphone works as well.

Comment: Works well on RHEL/Fedora24. Using a USB Hub may kill the resolution down to 640x480

Answer (score 8):

Check out [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30050/how-is-logitech-c510-hd-webcam/30201#30201) to this question.

[This page](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6471) shows the list of cameras which are UVC compatible, which lists the C615, so you should be all set by just plugging it in.

(I've never seen a Logitech webcam not work, they just seem to have their documentation a bit out of date.)

Comment: Thank you, I will provide the definitive answer when I buy it next week so people can get the confirmation.

Comment: I've bought the camera, you're right ,it's working, see the edit to my question.

Comment: @enedene Instead post your edit as a separate answer and mark it as the accepted answer, so we can vote you up!

Comment: Roger that @Jorge

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem with the Microphone on this Camera (HD C615) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The camera worked fine when I plugged it in but the Mic wasn't being recognized. I followed the instructions on the Skype website below and that fixed my issue:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/how-do-i-adjust-the-sound-settings-on-my-computer-and-in-skype-for-linux

Turns out that I needed to install PulseAudio Volume Control from within the Software Centre of Ubuntu to get it to work with my Camera's Mic. As soon as I did, it worked without me having to reboot. I'm not sure if this is just a random one-off on my end but it fixed my issue. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

I bought this camera and the video works fine, so does the audio. Skype on the other hand has video in and out but sound only in and dead silence out.

Comment: Skype working fine here. Check out the audio settings, it's not a camera problem.